# Getting the Taylor series for $\arctan(e^x-1)$

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Solving for the Taylor series of $\arctan(e^x-1)$:

What I do know is that the Taylor series for $\arctan(x)$, which is: $x-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^7}{7}+...$

Then, would not the Taylor series for this be: $(e^x-1)-\frac{(e^x-1)^3}{3}+\frac{(e^x-1)^5}{5}-\frac{(e^x-1)^7}{7}+...$, substituting each $x$ with $(e^x-1)$, for $\arctan(e^x-1)$?

However, Wolfram Alpha gave me a different answer, which was: $x+\frac{x^2}{2}-\frac{x^3}{6}-\frac{11x^4}{24}+...$

Why is this so? At what part/parts did I make a mistake?

Comment: The next stage is to generate the Taylor series for $e^x$ and substitute that for $e^x$ in your Taylor expression for $\arctan x$.

Comment: The series you have written converges to $\arctan(e^x-1)$, but it is not a *Taylor* series.

Comment: This isn't as grisly as it sounds, since $ \ e^x - 1 \ $ starts with $ \ x \ $ , so if you only want the terms up to $ \ x^5 \ $ for your series, you can stop at the third term in $ \ \arctan x \ $ since you'll only need to raise the _first_ term from $ \ e^x - 1 \ $ to the fifth power.